# Get calling component in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

How do you get access to the calling component in react?

```
function MyCallingComponent() {
  return <MyReadingComponent/>
}

function MyReadingComponent() {
  console.log(callingComponent.state)
}
```

Comment: pass the state as `porps` to component , or use `refs`

Comment: Could you provide some *context* - why do you think you need this? What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: coupling components is bad idea, `MyReadingComponent` shouldn't know anything about it's parent, instead it can declare some props, which can be filled by parent component

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't. The parent component can pass data and functions to the child via props, though. So for instance, if the parent needed a callback from the child in some circumstance:

```
function MyCallingComponent() {
    function callback() {
        // ...
    }
    return <MyReadingComponent callback={callback}/>;
}

function MyReadingComponent({callback}) {
    // ...use `callback` where appropriate...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

react uses unidirectional data flow, so if you need to access parent's state in your child component you need to pass it down as a prop.

```
class ParentComponent ...{
   state={ foo : 'A' }
   render(){
     return <ChildComponent foo={this.state.foo}/>
   }
 }
```

as @t-j-crowder has said if you need to pass data from child to parent you may use callback method.